de Rham Cohomology of disc using Poincaré Duality
According to the Poincar'e Duality, for a compact $n$-dimensional manifold,
$$H^k_{dR}(M)\simeq (H^{n-k}_{dR}(M)).$$
But this shows that for a closed $n$-disc $D^n=\{|x|\leq 1:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$,
$$H^n_{dR}(D^n)\simeq H^0_{dR}(D^n)\simeq\mathbb{R}.$$
I need clarification about what I am doing wrong. I doubt whether Poincar'e Duality is applicable or not. I need some help.

The version you cited is for manifolds without boundary. But $D^n$ is not a manifold without boundary.

@LukasHeger Why not make that comment an answer? :)

The version of Poincaré duality you cited only applies to manifolds without boundary. But $D^n$ is not a manifold without boundary.
